# SQL Replication Error (On Server Agent)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, replication

I have created the new replication. Now what is issue I am facing:

When I go to ​start the `'View Agent Snapshot Status'` Its just start working and First line shows "Starting Agent" and just keep working, working and continuously working.

.[image].

After sometime it show the following message:
"The replication agent has not logged a progress message in 10 minutes. This might indicate an unresponsive agent or high system activity. Verify that records are being replicated to the destination and that connections to the Subscriber, Publisher, and Distributor are still active."

[image]

I try the following solution that I found, I have increased the value of @HeartBeat_interval property of distributor from 10 to 30 but no success.

I have Sql Server 2008 R2.

any help will be appreciated really.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

May be this will help to someone else:

I did the following changes and my replication is working perfect.

```
1 - Job username and Job password must have full access and permission of windows.
2 - You must be logged In to user that you will use in the replication script to create replication.
```

That's all.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

I had the same behavior.
some of my articals are huge. while the replica's synch was over, the agent hanged up with the same message as yours.
after ~20 minutes it began running as expected.
I thought it is not not normal behavior, but after creating my second subscription, the error appeared again. it was gone approximately after 20 minutes.

I believe it is encounters high load of data (in case it is) and hangs up for while.
hope it helps